# Optimization of a linear PDE and operator formalism

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization, maxima-minima

Consider the reaction-diffusion PDE:
$$\partial_t m(x,t) = f(x,t) \, m(x,t) + K \, \partial_x^2 m(x,t)\,, \qquad 
m(x,t=0) = \frac{\exp\lbrace-x^2/(2\sigma_0^2)\rbrace}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_0^2}}$$
for $x\in (-\infty,\infty)$ and $t \in [0,T]$.
Assuming
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_0^{T} dt \, f(x,t) = \mathrm{cnst.} \qquad \text{and} \qquad f(x,t) \geq 0 $$
My goal is to gain some information on what profile of the forcing term $f(x,t)$ maximizes the final value of $m$ at the origin, i.e., $m(x=0,T)$. For example, it seems plausible from symmetry arguments that the optimal $f$ should be an even function of $x$. In addition, considering the fact that only diffusion can transport $m$ from other positions on the $x$ axis to $x=0$, one may intuitively argue that at time $t$, the optimal $f$ should be mostly distributed on an interval of radius $\sim \sqrt{K(T-t)}$ around $x=0$.

**Q1** Given the linearity of the PDE, are there specific classes of forcing profiles $f$ (eg, Gaussian, exponential, etc) for which the PDE can be directly solved and the result be optimized based on the parameters that defined the profile (eg, time-dependent variance for a Gaussian profile, time-dependent decay rate for an exponential function, etc)?

**Q2** (Probably the harder question) Is there a systematic way to find the optimal shape of $f$ (ie whether it should be, approximately, a Gaussian, exponential, box function, etc), or otherwise obtain some qualitative understanding of the shape? I have no idea how to even begin formulating this and what are some relevant techniques to approach such extremization problems.

**Update**
The solution to the PDE may formally be written, through the [Suzuki-Trotter decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_product_formula), as
$$
m(x,T) = \lim_{\delta t\to 0} (e^{\delta t  K \partial_x^2}  
e^{\delta t  f(x,(N-1)\delta t)} ) \ldots
(e^{\delta t  K \partial_x^2}  
e^{\delta t  f(x,\delta t)} ) 
(e^{\delta t  K \partial_x^2}  
e^{\delta t  f(x,0)} ) m(x,0)
$$
where $\delta t = T/N$.
The infinitesimal operators may be ordered (all forcing terms to the left and all diffusion terms to the right) by making use of the [Zussenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Zassenhaus_formula) to second order in $\delta t$:
\begin{equation}
m(x,T) = e^{\int_0^T dt f(x,t)} e^{(\delta t)^2 \sum_{j=1}^N j C_j} e^{TK\partial_x^2}m(x,0)
\end{equation}
with $C_j$ is the commutator arising from changing the order of $f(x,(M-j+1)\delta t)$ $K\delta t \partial_x^2$:
$$ e^{K\delta t \partial_x^2} e^{\delta t f(x,(M-j+1)\delta t)} 
 = e^{\delta t f(x,(M-j+1)\delta t)} e^{K\delta t \partial_x^2} e^{(\delta t)^2 C_j} + O(\delta t^3) $$
where $C_j = K \left(\partial_x^2 f(x,(M-j+1)\delta t) +2\left(\partial_x f(x,(M-j+1)\delta t)\right)\partial_x \right)$. In the limit of $N \to \infty$ and $\delta t =T/N \to 0$, after changing the summation index, we get
$$ (\delta t)^2 \sum_{j=1}^N j C_j \to \int_0^T dt \hspace{0.05cm} K (T-t) \left(\partial_x^2 f(x,t) + 2\partial_x f(x,t) \partial_x \right) $$

and therefore the solution may be written as
\begin{equation}
m(x,T) = e^{\int_0^T f(x,t) dt} 
e^{\int_0^T dt \hspace{0.05cm} K (T-t) \left( \partial_x^2 f(x,t) + 2\partial_x f \partial_x \right)} 
e^{TK\partial_x^2} 
m(x,0)
\end{equation}

This solution, if valid, holds for a general forcing term $f$. It, however, still contains the non-trivial operator $\partial_x f \partial_x$ in the exponent.  To use it for the maximization problem above, we first the symmetry of $f$ mentioned earlier and may argue that $\partial_x f\big\rvert_{x=0} = 0$ if $f$ is the optimal profile. We are then only left with
\begin{align} m(x=0,T) &= e^{\int_0^T f(0,t) dt} 
e^{\int_0^T dt \hspace{0.05cm} K (T-t) \partial_x^2 f(0,t)} e^{TK\partial_x^2} m(x,0) . 
\end{align}
Since the first two terms only contain scalar operators, they can be combined to get
\begin{equation}
m(x=0,T) = e^{\int_0^T dt \left( f(0,t) + K(T-t)\partial_x^2 f(0,t) \right)} e^{TK\partial_x^2} m(x,0) 
\end{equation}
or more explicitly
\begin{equation}
m(x=0,T) = e^{\int_0^T dt \left( f(0,t) + K(T-t)\partial_x^2 f(0,t) \right)} 
\int dy \frac{e^{\frac{-y^2}{4KT}}}{\sqrt{4\pi KT}} m(y,0)
\end{equation}

The integral part represents the diffusive spread of the initial profile from all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ to $x=0$. The exponential factor is the dependence of the final $m(x=0,T)$ on the forcing profile $f$.

**Q:** Are all the manipulations performed above valid (the Trotter decomposition of the formal solution, the ordering of the operators, discarding the $\partial_x$ operator given the assumption)?
If so, this formal solution to the PDE is rather simple as it only depends on $f(x=0,t)$ and its second derivative.

*PS:* I just realized it is not valid to simply set $\partial_x f \partial_x$ to zero, since this term, being in the exponential, generates terms such as $\left(\partial_x f \partial_x \right)^s \, e^{TK\partial_x^2}m(x,0)$ whose result depends on the higher-order deriverates of $f$ and $m_0$.

Comment: @MatthewCassell I don't think the equation for $u$ is what you have written, the integrating factor has non-vanishing $x$ derivatives and can't simple be factored out of the Laplacian.

Comment: You are right, I did not think about the fact that $f$ is spatially dependent. Removed.

Comment: Maybe it's worthwhile to explore $f$ for the steady state? $0 = f(x)m(x) + Km''(x)$. It's not what you're looking for, but it might spark some ideas.

Comment: @Aruralreader That's a nice idea but it seems to me given the positivity of $f$ and $m$, no such steady state exists (if you integrate both sides of the equation you wrote for all $x$, and assume for large $x$, $m$ goes to zero fast enough, the rhs would give a positive outcome while lhs is zero)